# iOS iPhone app - is it possible to pass arguments and get output from a Python script embedded in the app?

Tags: python, ios, iphone, python-3.x, cython

I have been researching this for a while but haven't had much success. Note that I am NOT trying to write an entire app in python (A lot of search results point to that).

I just have a python script which for example takes in a few numbers, does some sort of operation on the numbers and then outputs a string. Is it possible to embed this python script in my already existing Objective C app and execute it from my app? My iOS app needs to pass the numbers and get the resultant output string.

How can I do this?

**EDIT:**

I was able to use Pybee to get Python to be added to my app and my python script to at least be executed.

I used these 2 resources:
Use the Python 3.6 (using `cookiecutter` to build the Xcode project):
https://github.com/pybee/Python-iOS-template

Download the Python Apple support package for iOS from the link in above and add the libraries to the Xcode project.

After this, I created my AppDelegate to the Xcode project and it ran successfully and printed out my script usage in the NSLog console.

**However I am unable to figure out how to pass arguments to the script. Any idea?**

**EDIT 2:** I was able to get this to work. The python_argv and PySys_SetArgv can be used to pass arguments! Amazing!

This is how my main.m file:

```
//
//  main.m
//  A main module for starting Python projects under iOS.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#include <Python.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int ret = 0;
    unsigned int i;
    NSString *tmp_path;
    NSString *python_home;
    NSString *python_path;
    wchar_t *wpython_home;
    const char* main_script;
    wchar_t** python_argv;

    @autoreleasepool {

        NSString * resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

        // Special environment to prefer .pyo; also, don't write bytecode
        // because the process will not have write permissions on the device.
        putenv("PYTHONOPTIMIZE=1");
        putenv("PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1");

        // Set the home for the Python interpreter
        python_home = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Library/Python", resourcePath, nil];
        NSLog(@"PythonHome is: %@", python_home);
        wpython_home = Py_DecodeLocale([python_home UTF8String], NULL);
        Py_SetPythonHome(wpython_home);

        // Set the PYTHONPATH
        python_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PYTHONPATH=%@/Library/Application Support/com.blahblah.testapp/app:%@/Library/Application Support/com.blahblah.testapp/app_packages", resourcePath, resourcePath, nil];
        NSLog(@"PYTHONPATH is: %@", python_path);
        putenv((char *)[python_path UTF8String]);

        // iOS provides a specific directory for temp files.
        tmp_path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"TMP=%@/tmp", resourcePath, nil];
        putenv((char *)[tmp_path UTF8String]);

        NSLog(@"Initializing Python runtime");
        Py_Initialize();

        // Set the name of the main script
        main_script = [
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Library/Application Support/com.blahblah.testapp/app/testapp/app"
                                            ofType:@"py"] cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        if (main_script == NULL) {
            NSLog(@"Unable to locate testapp main module file");
            exit(-1);
        }

        // Construct argv for the interpreter
        python_argv = PyMem_RawMalloc(sizeof(wchar_t*) * argc);

        python_argv[0] = Py_DecodeLocale(main_script, NULL);
        for (i = 1; i < argc; i++) {
            python_argv[i] = Py_DecodeLocale(argv[i], NULL);

        }

        //NSLog(@"ARGS: %@",python_argv);
        python_argv[1]=(wchar_t *)[@"myargumentiwanttopass" cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
        PySys_SetArgv(2, python_argv);

        // If other modules are using threads, we need to initialize them.
        PyEval_InitThreads();

        // Start the main.py script
        NSLog(@"Running %s", main_script);

        @try {
            FILE* fd = fopen(main_script, "r");
            if (fd == NULL) {
                ret = 1;
                NSLog(@"Unable to open main.py, abort.");
            } else {
                ret = PyRun_SimpleFileEx(fd, main_script, 1);
                if (ret != 0) {
                    NSLog(@"Application quit abnormally!");
                } else {
                    // In a normal iOS application, the following line is what
                    // actually runs the application. It requires that the
                    // Objective-C runtime environment has a class named
                    // "PythonAppDelegate". This project doesn't define
                    // one, because Objective-C bridging isn't something
                    // Python does out of the box. You'll need to use
                    // a library like Rubicon-ObjC [1], Pyobjus [2] or
                    // PyObjC [3] if you want to run an *actual* iOS app.
                    // [1] http://pybee.org/rubicon
                    // [2] http://pyobjus.readthedocs.org/
                    // [3] https://pythonhosted.org/pyobjc/

                    UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"PythonAppDelegate");
                }
            }
        }
        @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"Python runtime error: %@", [exception reason]);
        }
        @finally {
            Py_Finalize();
        }

        PyMem_RawFree(wpython_home);
        if (python_argv) {
            for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
                PyMem_RawFree(python_argv[i]);
            }
            PyMem_RawFree(python_argv);
        }
        NSLog(@"Leaving");
    }

    exit(ret);
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: You'd normally write a Python function rather than a script and pass arguments in and out with PyObject_Call (or similar)

Comment: @DavidW Do you know how to use PyObject_CallFunction from Objective C to call and pass a parameter to a specific function in my Python .py file and get the output from it?

Comment: No. Unfortunately I don't know any objective C. I imagine the C examples should give a good starting point, but I'm definitely not someone who can answer this question.

Comment: @DavidW oh ok no worries, thanks for the suggestion!